Multiple issues after replacing pulseaudio with pipewire on Debian
First I removed pulseaudio usingsudo apt remove pulseaudio
then looked for the remainings of pulseaudio using whereis pulseaudio, after that I removed the directory by sudo rm -r and installed pipewire with sudo apt install pipewire-audio wireplumber pipewire-pulse pipewire-alsa libspa-0.2-bluetooth -y
After that terrible things started to happen:
first the Gnome desktop environment stops and shows a message saying that something wrong has happened call the admonitions
second so I switch to CLI and wrote startx to start dwm and after that wrote alsamixer the output is the host is down and the laptop completly became a soundless device
third I reinstalled the pulseaudio so the sound can come again but the sound only work for download videos through the wired headphones and the remaing is silent too the output of alsamixer is:
ALSA lib conf.c:4004:(snd_config_hooks_call) Cannot open shared library libasound_module_conf_pulse.so (libpulsecommon-16.1.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
ALSA lib control.c:1528:(snd_ctl_open_noupdate) Invalid CTL default
cannot open mixer: No such file or directory

and the out put of pulseaudio is:
pulseaudio: error while loading shared libraries: libpulsecommon-16.1.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

systemctl --user status pulseaudio

pulseaudio.service - Sound Service
    Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/user/pulseaudio.service, enabled)
    Active: inactive (dead)

and this packages installed with pulseaudio:
apulse/stable,stable,now 0.1.13-2 amd64 [installed] libcanberra-pulse/stable,stable,now 0.30-10 amd64 [installed] libkf5pulseaudioqt3/stable,stable,now 1.3-2+b1 amd64 [installed] libpulse-dev/stable,stable,now 16.1+dfsg1-2+b1 amd64 [installed] libpulse-mainloop-glib0/stable,stable,now 16.1+dfsg1-2+b1 amd64 [installed] libpulse0/stable,stable,now 16.1+dfsg1-2+b1 amd64 [installed] libpulsedsp/stable,stable,now 16.1+dfsg1-2+b1 amd64 [installed,automatic] pipewire-pulse/stable,stable,now 0.3.65-3+deb12u1 amd64 [installed,automatic] pulseaudio-utils/stable,stable,now 16.1+dfsg1-2+b1 amd64 [installed,automatic]

so why these three problems start to happen and how can I fix them?

What have you installed? There are more components required than the one package for it to work completely in the system. From here, the list is
wireplumber It is installed for the support of the session manager to PipeWire
pipewire-pulse  It is used as the replacement for the PulseAudio
pipewire-alsa   It is used for the support of ALSA
libspa-0.2-bluetooth    It is used for the Bluetooth support
I am on Mint with Ubuntu 24 base, and my list of packages with the work pulse in is:
libcanberra-pulse/noble,now 0.30-10ubuntu10 amd64 [installed]
libkf5pulseaudioqt3/noble,now 1.3-2build2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libpulse-dev/noble,now 1:16.1+dfsg1-2ubuntu10 amd64 [installed]
libpulse-mainloop-glib0/noble,now 1:16.1+dfsg1-2ubuntu10 amd64 [installed]
libpulse0/noble,now 1:16.1+dfsg1-2ubuntu10 amd64 [installed]
libpulse0/noble,now 1:16.1+dfsg1-2ubuntu10 i386 [installed,automatic]
pipewire-pulse/noble-updates,now 1.0.5-1ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]
pulseaudio-utils/noble,now 1:16.1+dfsg1-2ubuntu10 amd64 [installed]
pulsemixer/noble,noble,now 1.5.1-1.1 all [installed]

It's hard to be more specific without more specific details of the problem. The Arch wiki has helpful information as is often the case.

actually I installed all theses packages because i have acess to the interent and all these packages are mintion in each page but still there is no sound and can you tell me how I can be more specifc about my problem please

Pulse when I run Alasamixer  with pipe wire the out put is the  host is down.                                             And  when I run alsamixer with pulse audio said can’t run because of shared library libpulsecommon-16.so

Run this command and post response: systemctl --user status pipewire{,-pulse} wireplumber
Also these two: apt list --installed | grep pipewire, apt list --installed | grep pulse

I poste the respoend
